# calcular diferença entre duas datas em meses no R

Tags: r, datetime

Como calculo a diferença entre duas datas em meses no R?

Suponha as duas datas:

```
x <- as.Date("2014-01-07")
y <- as.Date("2015-03-17")
```

Consigo facilmente calcular em segundos, minutos, horas, etc usando a função `difftime`.

Mas ela não aceita meses :(

Com as seguintes funções consegui calcular, mas elas não devolvem frações de meses, como a `difftime`.

```
monthdiff <- function(x, y){
  x <- c(str_sub(x, 1, 4), str_sub(x, 5))
  y <- c(str_sub(y, 1, 4), str_sub(y, 5))

  12*(x[1]-y[1]) + (x[2] - y[2])
}

criar_anomes <- function(x){
  sprintf("%4d%02d", year(x), month(x))
}
```

Assim obtenho:

```
library(lubridate)
monthdiff(criar_anomes(y), criar_anomes(x))
[1] 14
```

Além de um jeito que retornasse a fração (Neste caso deveria ser algo com 14,33 acho) dos meses, gostaria de uma forma mais elegante do que essa.

Comment: Mas como você quer definir a fração de um mês? Pergunto porque cada mês tem uma quantidade de dias diferente.

Comment: Não tinha pensado nisso! Acho que dividir por 31 é ok

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primeiro, sem tratar fração do mês, existem algumas alternativas para pegar diferenças entre o mês do calendário. Exemplos:

```
x <- as.Date("2014-01-07")
y <- as.Date("2015-03-17")

# criando uma sequência
length(seq(x, y, by = "months")) - 1
[1] 14

# usando o zoo
library(zoo)
(as.yearmon(y) - as.yearmon(x)) * 12
[1] 14
```

Vale a pena frisar que isso é uma diferença do mês do calendário pois uma diferença entre 31 de janeiro e 01 de fevereiro, por essa definição, é de um mês.

A parte da fração do mês é mais complicada pois depende da forma que você definir a fração de um mês. Se você definir de uma forma simples, como a cada 30 dias ou 31 dias ou a cada 4 ou 5 semanas, aí bastaria usar o próprio `difftime` e dividir o resultado pelo número correspondente:

```
as.numeric(difftime(y, x, units = "days"))/30
[1] 14.46667
as.numeric(difftime(y, x, units = "days"))/31
[1] 14
```

Comment: Acho que em um primeiro momento não é necessário converter para numeric. Sem a conversão é possível fazer a maioria das operações, e mantém-se a opção de ser mudar a unidade facilmente.

Answer (score 3):

Eu encontrei o pacote `mondate` para fazer isso:

```
> library(mondate)
> t2 = as.mondate('2015-03-17')
> t1 = as.mondate('2014-01-07')
> t2 - t1
Time difference of 14.32 months
>
```

Comment: ótima resposta!